# bokeh overlay multiple plot objects in a GridPlot

Tags: python, bokeh

Say I have a class that holds some data and implements a function that returns a bokeh plot

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
class Data():
    def plot(self,**kwargs):
        # do something to retrieve data
        return bk.line(**kwargs)
```

Now I can instantiate multiple of these Data objects like `exps` and `sets` and create individual plots. If `bk.hold()` is set they'll, end up in one figure (which is basically what I want).

```
bk.output_notebook()
bk.figure()
bk.hold()
exps.scatter(arg1)
sets.plot(arg2)
bk.show()
```

[image]

Now I want aggregate these plots into a `GridPlot()` I can do it for the non overlayed single plots

```
bk.figure()
bk.hold(False)
g=bk.GridPlot(children=[[sets.plot(arg3),sets.plot(arg4)]])
bk.show(g)
```

[image]

but I don't know how I can overlay the scatter plots I had earlier as exps.scatter.

Is there any way to get a reference to the currently active figure like:

```
rows=[]
exps.scatter(arg1)
sets.plot(arg2)
af = bk.get_reference_to_figure()
rows.append(af) # append the active figure to rows list
bg.figure()     # reset figure

gp = bk.GridPlot(children=[rows])
bk.show(gp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Bokeh 0.7 the `plotting.py` interface has been changed to be more explicit and hopefully this will make things like this simpler and more clear. The basic change is that `figure` now returns an object, so you can just directly act on those objects without having to wonder what the "currently active" plot is:

```
p1 = figure(...)
p1.line(...)
p1.circle(...)

p2 = figure(...)
p2.rect(...)

gp = gridplot([p1, p2])
show(gp)
```

Almost all the previous code should work for now, but `hold`, `curplot` etc. are deprecated (and issue deprecation warnings if you run python with deprecation warnings enabled) and will be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

Ok apparently `bk.curplot()` does the trick

```
exps.scatter(arg1)
sets.plot(arg2)
p1 = bk.curplot()
bg.figure()     # reset figure
exps.scatter(arg3)
sets.plot(arg4)
p2 = bk.curplot()
gp = bk.GridPlot(children=[[p1,p2])
bk.show(gp)
```