# What happened to 'hold' in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

Lots of bokeh examples use the `hold` command.  I can see from the documentation that it's been deprecated since version 0.8.0
So I tried this:

```
x = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime", tools=Tools)
x.hold()
```

but no joy...`attribute 'hold' does not exist`

How do I update such examples to work on recent versions of bokeh?

As pointed out below, the answer to this question: [bokeh overlay multiple plot objects in a GridPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912632/bokeh-overlay-multiple-plot-objects-in-a-gridplot) says that `hold` is deprecated.

I think (from 3 seconds of experimentation), that `hold` commands can just be removed.  Since I don't know what it was *meant* to do, I can't verify this is correct :-).

I would be good to have that confirmed here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bokeh overlay multiple plot objects in a GridPlot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912632/bokeh-overlay-multiple-plot-objects-in-a-gridplot)

Comment: Edited question to address possible duplication question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: just to clarify, this question and answer refer to the old `hold()` plotting function, removed several years ago, and not to the more recent (and completely unrelated) [`Document.hold()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html#bokeh.document.document.Document.hold) method for pausing server updates)*

The `bokeh.plotting` API used to have a notion of an implicit "current plot". By default, every plotting function like `circle` or `rect` created a new plot. The `hold` function was intended to stop new plot creation, so multiple renderers could be added to the same plot. This was removed in favor of a more explicit interface that did not have a "current plot" notion. This provides more reliable interactions in the IPython notebook as well as server examples. To add multiple renderers on a single plot, it now looks like, for example:

```
p = figure(...)
p.circle(...)
p.rect(...)
```

Since all operations are now methods on explicit "plot" objects, there is no need for `hold` (so there is no replacement for it).